# Get specific field from a table with moodle Data manipulation API

Tags: mysql, moodle, moodle-api

I want to select all records from moodle data base where id is equal to a certain variable.Can anybody tell me what will be the moodle Data manipulation API syntax for it.

Here is **mysql query**

```
Select question from mdl_answers where id=$questionid;
```

I have tried

```
$queid[]= $queid[] = $DB->get_field('question_answers', 'id', array('question' => $questionid), MUST_EXIST);
$true=$queid[0];   // this i get
$false=$queid[1];   //this remains empty
```

But it only gives one record whereas i have more than one records assosiated to this id.

as you can see in the picture record 71 and 72 have same value 48 in next column i want to get these ids 71 and 72
[image]

Comment: You should never substitude params to SQL queries directly, it can lead to SQL Injections.

Comment: What do you mean by "this i get"

Comment: i only get value 71

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_field()` will only return a single value.

Either Use `get_records()` - https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#Getting_an_hashed_array_of_records

```
$answers = $DB->get_records('question_answers', array('question' => $questionid));
foreach ($answers as $answer) {
    switch ($answer->answer) {
        case 'True':
            $true = $answer->id;
            break;
        case 'False':
            $false = $answer->id;
            break;
      }
}
```

Or use `get_field()` like this

```
$true = $DB->get_field('question_answers', 'id', array('question' => $questionid, 'answer' => 'True'));
$false = $DB->get_field('question_answers', 'id', array('question' => $questionid, 'answer' => 'False'));
```